# Can cobalt pass the error type when kSbSystemPlatformErrorTypeConnectionError happended?

Tags: cobalt

For SSL test cases, it need to show system error dialogues, but in SbSystemRaisePlatformError, there is no detail error type to indicate which kind of error happend. And for preload case, if there is no network, it need to exit cobalt process,  so is there a way to get the detail type in this callback? eg. self signed certificate, expired certificate ...

```
https://self-signed.badssl.com/: Connection needs to be rejected and show system error dialog due to the self signed certificate.
https://expired.badssl.com/: Connection needs to be rejected and show system error dialog due to the expired certificate.

//src/starboard/shared/stub/system_raise_platform_error.cc
SbSystemPlatformError SbSystemRaisePlatformError(
    SbSystemPlatformErrorType type,
    SbSystemPlatformErrorCallback callback,
    void* user_data) {
  SB_UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(callback);
  SB_UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(user_data);
  std::string message;
  switch (type) {
    case kSbSystemPlatformErrorTypeConnectionError:
      message = "Connection error.";
      break;
#if SB_API_VERSION < 6
    case kSbSystemPlatformErrorTypeUserSignedOut:
      message = "User is not signed in.";
      break;
    case kSbSystemPlatformErrorTypeUserAgeRestricted:
      message = "User is age restricted.";
      break;
#endif
    default:
      message = "<unknown>";
      break;
  }
  SB_DLOG(INFO) << "SbSystemRaisePlatformError: " << message;
  return kSbSystemPlatformErrorInvalid;
}
```

Comment: What is the expected user action for these different errors? How does knowing the difference help?

Comment: Hi david, if it can get the detail type of the net error,  with preload mode for example,  it can decide to exit cobalt process or not, and shows the detail error msg to users to make users know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

We can consider it for a future Starboard version, but since this crosses a controlled API, which is frozen up to version 6, we can't change it in the short term.